# Does the current ARtoolkit support displaying POIs through camera?

Tags: ios, gps, augmented-reality, artoolkit, point-of-interest

I see it is now supporting GPS and compass for iOS [Includes OpenGL ES2.x support, integration with GPS and compass, and automatic camera calibration utilities.](https://artoolkit.org/). I know [wikitude](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/ios) has supported POIs and retrieving POIs data. Does ARtoolkit have anything similar to this? If not, can I create my own POIs points and database? Would love to know how to get started for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARToolkit is meant to do marker-based Augmented reality.

What you want for POI is location+orientation based Augmented reality, so no, ARToolkit does not have it.

To get started get a database of locations and just use a 3D Engine (probably Unity) to match the camera position in the world to your location and the rotation tot he rotation of the phone.

Comment: Should I use Unity with ARToolkit? Would you mind pointing me to some resources so that I can get my feet into the door?

Comment: ARToolkit does not provide you any of the support for POI display, so no, you should not use it. Look for how to read the sensors from Unity and how camera works.